# Why does this call to Trigger keySet() throw a null pointer exception?

Tags: trigger, null-pointer, set

I have a simple trigger like:

```
trigger littleTrigger on Custom__c (before insert) {
    Set<Id> idSet = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
    //Some stuff
}
```

Why could the second line throw a null pointer exception?

When I code it like:

```
trigger littleTrigger on Custom__c (before insert) {
    Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();

    for (Custom__c d : Trigger.New)
        idSet.add(d.Id);
}
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Trigger Context Variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) documentation:

- Trigger.new:  this sObject list is only available in insert and update triggers
- Trigger.newMap:  this map is only available in before update, after insert, and after update triggers

In a "before insert" trigger, the sObjects don't yet have ID values so a Trigger.newMap keyed by the sObject ID can't be made available and Trigger.newMap returns null. But a list of the sObjects (again without IDs) can be made available.

Comment: Keith comments are true, but why is the second option working at all? you are using trigger.new in a before insert call and retrieving the record Id which it doesn't exist yet

Comment: @Emilio I think the "works fine" in the question here just means no null pointer exception. The `idSet` will end up with only one entry, the value `null`, and so is not useful. For this "before insert" case, the position in the `Trigger.new` list can sometimes be used to identify the SObjects. Also nothing can be referencing the SObjects as they are not yet inserted so their ID values aren't/can't be needed.